# Does WMP store the files or its history in a hidden location?

Tags: command-line, history, windows-media-player

Does WMP have a hidden storage for recently/history file that I can access?

I'm asking because my mother and I watched footage from a SD Card on WMP of someone stealing from our home and damaging some of our property. My mom erased the footage assuming I had it saved.

Can someone help me or give advice on how to get footage back, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

#### Does WMP have a hidden storage for recently/history file that I can access?

If it is still on the recent play list then yes:

1. Start Registry Editor.
2. Locate, and then click the following registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Player\RecentFileList
   ```

Source: [How to delete the recent play list from Windows Media Player](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-delete-the-recent-play-list-from-windows-media-player-095410a9-1f37-8e9b-222e-c520757d4eca)

> how to get footage back, if possible?

See this Community FAQ: [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)